# No route matches so I cannot display my comments on my show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am trying to display my comments on my show page.

I have created the comments controller and rendered a page to display the comments on the show page however when I create a comment I get a routing error. Please see error below:

error message: 
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"hairstyles", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`

The behaviour I would like is for when the user creates a comment it redirects to the show page and shows the comment.

Thank you in advance!

comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end


def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
    @comment.save
    redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle)
end


  def destroy
  end
end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end
```

show page:

```
show.html.erb

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <%= cl_image_tag @hairstyle.photo, width: 300, height: 200, crop: :fill %>
    <h1><%= @hairstyle.name %></h1>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.description%></p>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.category%></p>
    <p><%= @hairstyle.video_url %></p>
  </div>
</div>
 <div>
    <%= link_to 'Back', hairstyles_path %>
 </div>

<h6>Comments for: <%= @hairstyle.name %> <small><%= %></small></h6>
<h2>
  <%= pluralize @hairstyle.comments.size, "comment" %>
</h2>

<div id="comments">
  <% if @hairstyle.comments.blank? %>
    Be the first to leave a comment for <%= @hairstyle.name %>
  <% else %>
    <% @hairstyle.comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/show', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= render 'comments/form', comment: @comment %>
```

comments/show page which is rendered above:

```
<p><%= comment.content %></p>
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :hairstyles do
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create ]
  resources :saved_hairstyles, only: [:new, :create]
end

  resources :saved_recipes, only: :destroy
  resources :comments, only: :destroy
  resources :hairdressers
end
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message which indicates your problem.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"hairstyles", :id=>nil}, 
missing required keys: [:id]
```

It is trying to go to the *show* action in the *hairstyles* controller without an ID param.  Why is it trying to go there?

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
  @comment.save
  redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle) # this line
end
```

`@comment` does not have a hairstyle. You need to add the association with something like:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
  @hairstyle.comments << @comment
  @comment.save
  redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle)
end
```

**Edit** after seeing the repo I was able to track down the issues and sort it out.

Quick tips:

1. Your logs are not telling you why your model validation is failing. So, you want to make sure you're running this in development, catch errors, and log them. (eg. you can user `save!` instead of `save` to ensure it throws errors.
2. Your code is a little wiry. I recommend reading up on best practices for Ruby on Rails. You should really also have tests in your repo.

**Solution** (as far as I could test without doing it all):

in `hairstyle.rb` model you have these lines:

```
validates :content, presence: true
validates :content, length: { minimum: 20 }
```

But `Hairstyle` doesn't have a content field. So right off the bat, you can't save any Hairstyles (at least I couldn't).

in `comment.rb` model you have this line:

```
 belongs_to :hairdresser
```

But in your Schema, `Comment` does not have a `hairdresser_id` field. So validation fails because `Hairdresser must exist` is thrown. But then when I include a Hairdresser, it throws `(can't write unknown attribute hairdresser_id)`. So, you're going to want to run this migration:

```
rails g migration AddHairdresserToComments hairdresser:references
```

That should just about fix it.

Of course, you'll need to make sure that you're passing all of the correct parameters along the way. I had a tough time testing your models because *everything* is required by you. Personally, I like to keep it simple. *Only* require that which is absolutely necessary. Everything else should be left up to the user.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response. I have amended my code and now it does indeed redirect to the right page (my show page) which is great! However the strange thing is that the comments do not show up on my show page :S Also when I go to the console and do Rails c  - Comment.all it shows as an empty array, strange no? Any ideas. Thank you Angela

Comment: Is this what you mean: ```Hairstyle Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "hairstyles".* FROM "hairstyles" WHERE "hairstyles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10
   (0.7ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/hairstyles/2
Completed 302 Found in 160ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)```

Comment: Typically, when you're experiencing bugs, it's helpful to repeat your action (eg. CREATE a comment) and look at your logs. Don't post logs in comments but append them to your original question. I can see from your logs that it's performing a "ROLLBACK". Your comments are not being saved.

Comment: Oh ok oops newbie here. I was thinking how I could avoid pasting all of that in a comment. I will do that next time. Yes it's rolling back at line 9 which is this  ```@hairstyle.comments << @comment``` I'll keep looking.Thanks

Comment: I can tell you that it's probably because model validation failed. Does the model `Hairstyle` have the line `has_many :comments` in it? Does the `Comment` model have special validations that are failing (eg. must have text inside it)?

Comment: Hello yes my validations are correct. I am pulling my hair out about this. I am not sure if this is allowed on here but if you could quickly check my repo on github I'd be forever grateful. I do not know what the issue is :( https://github.com/Angela-Inniss/hair-do

Comment: Check my updated solution. I've edited my original answer after testing your app

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your detailed response. I am  a baby rubyist and things still aren't making that much sense at the moment so I just try things out and see ( which you can see). I will add the hairdresser migration. One last question: when you say " everything is required by you" do you mean that I have validations on everything? I.e" validates xx presence true"". Are you saying that you only validate what is necessary and less is more? Thanks! Angela :)

Comment: Yes, this is more a matter of subjectivity, but I believe validating the "presence true" on everything is really restrictive. Users don't like having to fill out 10 fields in a form to get started. Like, for example, StackOverflow doesn't require that you fill out your entire profile before you can save and move on. If you put "presence true" on all of those fields, it's going to be cumbersome! Plus, why force people to add data? That only means you have to pay for that extra storage! I generally only require the things that would be breaking my app if they didn't exist.

Comment: Hehe ok good advice ill take that on board going forward! I think ill stop adding features for now and tidy up my code first. Thanks for the help and advice again. I'll test when I'm back at a computer and post if it works. Until then... :)

Answer (score 0):

At no point do you associate the comment to the hairstyle, so when you write

```
def create
  `…`
  redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle)
end
```

@comment.hairstyle is nil, hence your error.

Update your create method to the following and that should do it

```
def create
  @hairstyle = Hairstyle.find(params[:hairstyle_id])
  @comment = @hairstyle.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.save
  redirect_to hairstyle_path(@comment.hairstyle)
end
```